# Public URL of a document version with versioning S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, versioning

I am trying to use the amazon S3 versioning.
So I manage to create a object and display versions and select the version of a well Preci.

But I block or it is for public display url of a document versioning

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
prefix = "path/file"
obj = s3.list_object_versions(bucket: 'bucket', prefix: prefix)
```

I get the version and I want are public url

```
obj.versions.first
```

I can not find the method that allows me to have the public URL

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_object_versions-instance_method), the `version` object (ie, what you get upon `obj.versions.first`) has a `version_id` key.

You can use that ID to get that version [using REST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html#retrieve-obj-version-rest) - you just add a `versionId=<THE_ID>` to your query string.

But I'm not really sure that counts as a public URL. It probably needs you to be authenticated - I don't think it's a good idea to have every version of an object publicly accessible, so probably you just can't.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,
Actually my url is not secure, so I used a test url public but that does not work because it says access denied, and yet I added him:

```
@bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new(BUCKET)
url = @bucket.object(name)
url.public_url(acl: 'public-read')
```

So adding a new permission I manage to not have the access denied but now he told me that the file is not yet well I use the public_url,

I have forgotten something?

```
@bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new(BUCKET)
url = @bucket.object(@name)
url.public_url
```